# flex 4: how can i connect two lines with a small curve?

Tags: flex4, line

I have the following code to draw two lines that connect to each other at one point:

```
<s:Line right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:RadialGradientStroke weight="3">
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0" color="0xAB9A9C" alpha="0.5" />
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.8" color="0x8A797B"  />
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.9" color="0x524244" />
        </s:RadialGradientStroke>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Line>

<s:Line right="0" left="0" bottom="0">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:RadialGradientStroke weight="3">
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0" color="0xAB9A9C" alpha="0.5" />
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.8" color="0x8A797B"  />
            <s:GradientEntry ratio="0.9" color="0x524244" />
        </s:RadialGradientStroke>
    </s:stroke>
</s:Line>
```

how can i create a small curve in the connection between the two lines?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use FXG to create an arc between the two lines.  It may be easier to draw both lines and the arc as a single Path.  See the documentation for more:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS5B6A8436-0FF5-4029-8524-C7C1106C483D.html